# DrawerLayout very laggy when closing after clicking item. Cause Realm?

Tags: android, mvvm, realm, android-livedata

When I'm pressing on the item in my navigationView I call getSupportFM and load fragment. In the fragment I attach ViewModel and in the constructor and then I load my data from network and in this time in the method `.doOnNext` save it's in Realm database.

```
public MyViewModel() {
    repository = new MyRepository();
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    liveData = new LiveRealmResults<>(realm.where(MyClass.class).findAllAsync());
}
```

My network request:

```
apiInterface.getMyData(page)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .doOnNext(myDataRequest -> {
                if (myDataRequest.getMyData().size() != 0) {
                    List<MyData> myData= myDataRequest.getMyData();
                    try (Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
                         realm.executeTransaction(r -> r.insertOrUpdate(myData));
                    }
                }
            })
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

My fragment:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //we should to do this.
    //https://developer.android.com/jetpack/arch/livedata#the_advantages_of_using_livedata
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(MyViewModel.class);
    viewModel.getMyLiveData().observe(this, stateObserver);
}
```

And Observer:

```
private Observer<List<MyData>> stateObserver = new Observer<List<MyData>>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(@Nullable List<MyData> myData) {
        if (myData.size() != 0) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            adapter.updateAdapter(myData);
        }
    }
};
```

But, if I deleting this line DrawerLayout isn't laggy when I'm swapping between fragments with navigationView. In the first time, I load 20 elements from network.

I've spent two days to fix it but I don't understand how to do this.

```
viewModel.getMyLiveData().observe(this, stateObserver);
```

Comment: Nothing seems out of the ordinary, you'll need to use method profiling and post here what seems slowest.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll try and post it in 3-5 hours